# VB.Net Slider with Range control

Tags: vb.net, slider, range

I am looking for a slider control that allows you to adjust the range as well. An example of this would be the yahoo finance charts for any stock symbol where you can view certain sections of the trading history. It allows you to increase/decrease the time values, and then a slider that allows you to move that range anywhere within the history. However, this would be for VB.Net forms.  Hope this makes sense. You can view a sample here (the slider is under the From and To fields):

http://ca.finance.yahoo.com/echarts?s=RIM.TO#symbol=rim.to;range=3m;compare=;indicator=volume;charttype=area;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=off;source=undefined;

Answer (score 4):

> I am looking for a slider control that allows you to adjust the range as well.

I think what you want is a [trackbar control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.aspx)

Comment: I found something I can work with:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2275/C-RangeBar-control